# How to implement a message queue in Google App Engine / Google Data Store (JDO)

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, google-cloud-datastore

I want to implement a message Queue (F.I.F.O) for an application deployed in Google App Engine. The application uses JDO to access the Google DataStore. I have exposed a REST API which can be called from any mobile device. The diagram below should clearly indicate what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

A pool of mobile devices call the REST API to en-queue a message into the queue. The Message entity contains a creation timestamp and message status fields. Message Status is set to ACTIVE initially. Another pool of mobile devices will call a REST API to fetch a message. At that moment the datastore is queried for ACTIVE message entites sorted in ascending order of creation timestamp. The message status is then set to DELIVERED and the message is returned to the device.

Problem occurs when then are concurrent requests from Consumer devices. Multiple devices receive the same message.

I have a model class Message

```
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
@Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
private String id;
@Persistent
private String message;
@Persistent
private Date created;
@Persistent
private MessageStatus status;
```

MessageStatus enum has the following statues

```
    public enum MessageStatus {
    ACTIVE, DELIVERED, ACKNOWLEDGED
}
```

I have a Data Access Class MessageDAO

```
public Message fetchMessage() {
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Message message = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = pm.currentTransaction();
            transaction.setIsolationLevel(Constants.TX_READ_COMMITTED);
            transaction.begin();            

            Query query = pm.newQuery(Message.class);           
            query.setFilter("status == 'ACTIVE'");          
            query.setOrdering("created asc");


            List<Message> messageList = (List<Message>) query.execute();            
            if (messageList != null && !messageList.isEmpty()) {
                message = messageList.get(0);
                message.setStatus(MessageStatus.DELIVERED);             
            }

            transaction.commit();
        } finally {
            if (transaction != null && transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }

            pm.close();
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you do long polling for messages from the devices. If that's the case then there isn't any real value in using a task queue. Queue are more for jobs/business processing to be executed.

You should rather just have endpoints and call the server with a timestamp of the last message you have. Then every device will retrieve the exact same result set from the query out of the datastore. Memcache will help with the quotas.

You can reference how Dropbox does it, they use a delta token they send to receive a group of any new folder/file changes.

Comment: Tjorriemorrie : I am not using task queue. Task Queue is not relavent here. By pull queue i meant that the devices call the rest services to pull the message instead of server pushing it into the devices